# Python for Android : apk stuck on loading screen

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am trying to convert my python 3 code into an apk using Python-For-Android's tool. They have recently added python 3 support albeit it being experimental.

It may be of importance to note that my whole program is written in pure python and uses no kivy frameworks, it's graphical interface is all done in tkinter, no extra modules apart from the ones that already come python have been used.

I have compiled my programs (the user interface references the 'brains') stored in the following directiories

```
package\
    __pycache__
    __init__.py
    Solver.py
main.py
__pycache__
```

with python-for-android and I've then got the resultant apk, this is on debian by the way, if it makes any difference, which I have installed, without any problems so far on my phone...

**It's only when I launch the application, which has installed without problem that it goes to a white loading screen with loading in the top left corner but never gets past it**

I read somewhere it's because of a Java error, I understand this may have been used to compile the programs...

**My question, after all of this background stuff is how do I fix it as I don't know much about Java?**

EDIT: I've ran this on a virtual machine and got an error... please see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqCk5.png)

EDIT 2: [Javac warnings whilst compiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K4hw.png)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a supported use of python-for-android. In order for your app to function, you need to interact with one of the available bootstraps - sdl2, pygame or webview. Kivy knows how to interact with the sdl2 and pygame bootstraps, and the webview bootstrap just uses an Android Webview to display content from a local web server (flask). If you want to use Tkinter, you would need to create a bootstrap for it (either a new bootstrap in p4a itself, or some python code to connect Tkinter to an existing bootstrap like sdl2).

Comment: Oh I see, so basically the way to get round this is sort of recode the graphics in Kivy? If so, how can I still implement my solver part within it? Also, if this isn't an option where would I start in creating a bootstrap?

Comment: Also, please see edit for new information... ran it on a virtual machine and got an error

Comment: Tkinter has no idea what to do on Android. You have to provide some way to let it render on the screen and accept input events from Android. For SDL2 and Pygame, which both use OpenGL, we handle this by providing some form of GLSurfaceView and passing input events received by the Java activity class to the appropriate SDL2 and Pygame methods. Webview just uses a Webview as previously stated. As for the error, you're running on an Android emulator which does not support ARM or has a buggy ARM translation layer.

Comment: Oh alright I understand whats going on now! Thanks. The emulator used was Android x86 as the SDK is installed on the linux virtual machine I've been developing with and it won't work as it's too much for the resources available, so I'll just have to get a copy of the SDK's emulators on my native system. But thank you for the advice... do you have any ideas of alternative ways to compile python into apks?

Comment: p4a builds all apps for ARM, so they won't work in an x86 emulator without a working translation layer. You can run them in an ARM emulator (though ARM emulators are slower - I usually do all of my testing on a physical device). I know there are some other projects out there which let you create Python Android apps, but I don't know that any will do what you're trying to do without needing the same work of connecting Tkinter to Android.

Comment: Actually, I believe you can actually create an x86 APK with the new toolchain, but I've never tried it and I don't know how well it works.

Comment: To all other stack overflow users: I'm sorry about the chat in comments, I just don't have enough reputation yet...

Comment: Which toolchain are we talking about here? In Kivy?

Comment: The new p4a toolchain (PyPI version, master branch on GitHub, or android_new target in buildozer).

Comment: Oh right, cheers, and but will it only work on x86 devices not ARM?

Comment: p4a only builds APKs for one architecture at a time. By default, it will build for either armeabi or armeabi-v7a. You can specifically set the arch to x86 or x86_64 (or arm64-v8a, which doesn't completely work). But the resulting APK will only work on the arch it was compiled for. (FYI - most x86 Android devices use libhoudini, which is an ARM translation layer, so ARM APKs can usually run on x86 devices, just not the other way around and not on the default SDK emulators).

Comment: I see, I'll recompile now with x86 and then x86_64 versions and see if I get anything

Comment: I compiled with x86, it didn't like x86_64 for some reason but did so with the --debug command added as well and it's not giving me an errors apart from some javac warnings (please see post edit) it's not saying anything that could show something's not going to plan

Comment: You can ignore those warnings, they won't hurt anything.

Comment: Alright, I've tried the x86 version on the x86 emulator but nothing different happens, in fact the same error message comes up, and I made sure I was running the right version but it looks like my best bet is to reprogram the UI, which was going to probably happen at some point anyway...

Comment: Well yes, like I already said. You need to set up Tkinter to render its display in Android somehow. Really, unless you have a massive complex app it might be easier to rewrite using Kivy, which will work on Windows, Linux, OS X, Android and iOS.

Comment: I will at some point then but can I still integrate my python 3 solver module into the Kivy UI?